# Js can't read property of an input on a Rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i've been trying to give an input some action when I press enter or tab out of it, but this specific text field which i've given id as 'address'. 
Some code:

```
document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 9 || key === 13) { 
        alert(key);
    }
});

<%= form.text_field :address, {id: 'address'} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When is your code called ?

It has to be called when the DOM has been fully loaded.

In your case :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    document.getElementById('address').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key === 9 || key === 13) { 
            alert(key);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set listeners after the DOM has been loaded.